# How can I run the javascript code with eval

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, eval

How can I run the javascript code with eval

Here is what I tried

```
<div class="col-md-4 black" >

<% @unit.attempts.order("created_at DESC").each do |attempt| %>
<p ></p>
<p id="log"><%= attempt.body %></p>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 run">
  <div class="view-lines">
    <h2>app.js</h2>
    <%= form_for [@unit, @attempt] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body,class: "editor"%>
    <%= f.submit "Run"%>
    <% end %>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $(".editor")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code,{
        lineNumbers: true,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        mode: "javascript",
        matchBrackets: true
    });
   });
    try {
  const v= $(item).find('.editor').val();
  const resultContainer = $('.black');
  const result = eval(v);
  
  resultContainer.innerHTML = result;
  } catch (error) {
  resultContainer.innerHTML = error;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Take the quotes off?  `'v'` is a literal string that doesn't mean anything.  Where as `v` could be a variable pointing to a string, that contains valid javascript code

Comment: Thank you, I will fix my question. it's still not working

Comment: What is `item`? Should use CodeMirror API to get the code from inside also

Comment: @Taplar I add it just because I want to add value to v= ('.editor').val();

Comment: @charlietfl  I add it just because I want to add value to v= ('.editor').val();  how can I add this one ('.editor').val();

Comment: You have tags div not closed. Oh, and [you should never use eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)